# What style is this vintage illustration?

Tags: vector, logo, illustration, style-identification

I'm looking for images similar to this one to use in a design but i'm unsure of what to search for. What style would you call this image? And how were illustrations like this created originally?

[image]

Comment: Which part of it are you wanting a term for?

Comment: the illustration

Comment: It is a valid question, but on this site it is on hold becouse normally the question should be redacted in a way it does not depend only on the image itself, so that can be searched by text. :o)

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty close to syles used for [Etching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etching) & [Wood cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodcut).

Here's some examples I got from googling the following...

**"Etched illustration style"**

[image]
<sub>(source: [victorianweb.org](http://www.victorianweb.org/art/illustration/bewick/18.jpg))</sub>

**"Wood cut illustration style"**

[image]